# Can you clean up Print_R output

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I am getting this from a `print_r` output:

```
Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => http://www.ls.bouwmanbv.nl [1] => http://www.ls.bouwmanbv2.nl [2] => http://www.ls.bouwmanbv3.nl [3] => http://www.ls.bouwmanbv4.nl )
```

How can I make it skip empty `Array ()` and remove the `[#] =>` so that I get a list like this:

```
http://www.ls.bouwmanbv.nl
http://www.ls.bouwmanbv2.nl
http://www.ls.bouwmanbv3.nl
http://www.ls.bouwmanbv4.nl
```

This is the code in question:

```
<?php
$user_  = JFactory::getUser();
$db     = JFactory::getDBO();
$levels = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels($user->id);

foreach($levels as $key => $level)
{
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query  = 'SELECT title FROM #__pf_projects';
  $query .= ' WHERE access = ' . $level;
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $results = $db->loadColumn();
  print_r($results);
}
```

Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use `print_r`? Do you want to just print array items?

Comment: Don't use `print_r()`?

Comment: To skip empty arrays, just do `if(empty($results)) continue;` right before your `print_r()`.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I did not know that and I added it in. Works perfectly. Thank you for dealing with one part of the problem. Really nice.

Comment: @nickb I tried `var_dump()` but it brings same sort of list. When I do a echo I get ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are trying to `echo` rather than `print_r` for that you can use the following:

```
foreach($levels as $key => $level)
{
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query  = 'SELECT title FROM #__pf_projects';
    $query .= ' WHERE access = ' . $level;
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadColumn();

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both iterations of your answer. And both work perfectly. I need to wait to accept as answer. Thank you very much for this!

I have been trying to get a echo out of it for almost 2 hours now and gave up on it. So thanks for saving me another 2 hours of work.

Comment: I just did but needed to wait due to a timer. A solution like this deserves the V absolutely. I wish I could Like as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$user_  = JFactory::getUser();
$db     = JFactory::getDBO();
$levels = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels($user->id);

foreach($levels as $key => $level)
{
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query    = 'SELECT title FROM #__pf_projects';
    $query .= ' WHERE access = ' . $level;
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadColumn();
    if(empty($results)) continue;
    foreach($results as $result) {
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

You can use `if(empty($results)) continue;` to skip empty arrays, and then a foreach loop to list the array contents.